# How can I use css wildcard selectors and use the wildcard value as an attribute with scss

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have a set up where I'd like to select elements based on partial class in scss.

I know of the wildcard selector which I could use `div[class*='-suffix']` however within the class definition, I'd like to use that wildcard value. For example:

```
.{prefix}-glyph
{
   @include mymixin({prefix})
}
```

Where {prefix} is the wildcard prefix I wish to match against.

Is this possible?

Comment: You have this slightly backwards, as well as missing a pound symbol in the class.  Can you post the mixin you are trying to write/use?  I can show you whats wrong.

Comment: sorry, the code was supposed to be pseudo-code. What I mean is that the item matched in {prefix} is the same as the value passed in to the mixin

Comment: How do you expect Sass to know what value to capture and pass to your mixin?

Comment: That's why I'm wondering if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, though don't see why you would want to do this?  Its requires more typing:

Mixin

```
@mixin myMixin($name) {

  .#{$name}-name {
      @content;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
@include myMixin(class) {
    // YOUR STYLES
};
```

Output

```
.class-name {
    // YOUR STYLES
}
```

Comment: A constraint I have is that I cannot modify the mixin. The context is we are leveraging our content management system to display different glyphs depending on the class applied within the content system. Currently I have:

`.basket-glyph { @include myMixin(basket); }`

`.shoe-glyph { @include myMixin(shoe); }`

Repeated many times

Comment: @ElFik usually if you have a constraint like this you should mention it as part of the question, as well as any other constraints you have.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are wanting, but if you are trying to simplify it, you can create a list of the glyph names, and then loop through them to create the css.  Example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/d968c36c71f94190880d

Comment: Thanks Sean, this is something I wasn't aware that I could do (never studied scss, just had to pick it up on the job). It doesn't fully do what I was wanting, but it looks to be the best option with the limitations of css.