# Regex-like CSS Attribute Selector Wildcard Capture

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tocolor-red">    tocolor </div>
<div class="tocolor-blue">   tocolor </div>
<div class="tocolor-green">  tocolor </div>
<div class="tocolor-yellow"> tocolor </div>
```

Instead of having to repeat CSS code like the snippet below for each color...

```
.tocolor-red{
  background: red;
}
.tocolor-red::before {
  content: "red";
}
```

... is there a way to write a CSS rule that captures the color from the css class instead?  For the sake of due diligence, I've looked up attribute selectors already and I've noticed that there are a number of ways you can use wildcards in css already.  However, I haven't found anything that would allow me to capture the wildcard text and as part of a rule.

If regex worked for CSS, the rule would look something like this:

```
.tocolor-([\w+]) {
   background: $1;
}
.tocolor-([\w+]:before {
   content: $1;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407665/how-can-i-use-css-wildcard-selectors-and-use-the-wildcard-value-as-an-attribute?rq=1

Comment: you cannot actually use the attribute value of an html attribute as a value for a css rule, but using sass or less you can generate each rules needed in  loop

Comment: that's a nice idea, easily done with JS tho.

Comment: Css isn't really able to do this. As you are already suggesting you might need languages that compile to css (less, sass, scss) but then you have to ad the rule for every color.

Comment: Why would you even think Sass is capable of doing something like this?  Sass compiles to CSS and that's it.

Comment: @cimmanon A sass example :) http://blackfalcon.roughdraft.io/4615645-iterate-list-to-produce-placeholder-classes so it generates the rules you need but of course it will not extract anything from the html . Just use an efficient method or the right tools ;)

Comment: @cimmanon Well, although it doesn't look like you can "capture" the wildcard, it does look like you can pass arguments to Sass mixins, like so: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-arguments

Comment: @GCyrillus And?  The OP is not asking how to generate selectors.

Comment: @cimmanon no but he is already told it cannot be done and that he shoud (imho) go for a proper method or tool. :)   ?? and you mark this as duplicate pointing straight at a sass question ?!?

Comment: I am recommending this question be reopened, because the other question is specifically about Sass.  For this question, I am looking for a general solution to the problem, including a Sass one if there is one.

Comment: @stephen There is no "Sass" solution to be had here.  Until browser vendors start supporting Sass, you're limited by what CSS offers.  Sass only compiles to CSS, end of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your wildcard:

```
div[class^='.tocolor-'] {
    background: red;
}
```

But if you are looking to use variables, you should take a look at SASS:

http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Ah, but what if I want `tocolor-blue` to show me blue instead, without having to write a second rule?

Comment: if you are looking to use variables on selectors, you should take a look at SASS:

http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 2):

CSS has no means to support regular expression captures, while you could select all elements with a class that begins with the string `tocolor-`, CSS has no means of capturing the value of the string to apply it to a rule.

Incidentally, and somewhat belatedly, one way to do this with JavaScript:

```
// retrieve all elements containing the string 'tocolor-':
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="tocolor-"]'),

// declaring two variables for use in later loops:
    classes, colorString;

// iterating over the (Array-like) collection of elements,
// using Function.prototype.call() to be able to apply the
// Array.prototype.forEach() method on the collection:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (elem) {
    // 'elem' is the individual node of the collection
    // over which we're iterating.

    // creating an Array of the classes from the element:
    classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem.classList, 0);

    // creating a new Array, using Array.prototype.map():
    colorString = classes.map(function (c) {
        // 'c' is the specific class of the Array of classes
        // over which we're iterating.

        // if the current class ('c') begins with the string
        // 'tocolor-' then we return that class
        if (c.indexOf('tocolor-') === 0) {

            // after first replacing the 'tocolor-' string
            // with an empty string:
            return c.replace('tocolor-','');
        }
    });

    // setting the color of the element ('elem') to
    // the string found:
    elem.style.color = colorString;
});
```

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="tocolor-"]'),
  classes, colorString;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(elem) {
  classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem.classList, 0);
  colorString = classes.map(function(c) {
    if (c.indexOf('tocolor-') === 0) {
      return c.replace('tocolor-', '');
    }
  });
  elem.style.color = colorString;
});
```

```html
<div class="tocolor-red">tocolor</div>
<div class="tocolor-blue">tocolor</div>
<div class="tocolor-green">tocolor</div>
<div class="tocolor-yellow">tocolor</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with SASS, since I've never really used it.